# i have a code of python and in the last line for printing 2d list it prints many time and the output is wrong and i am a beginner

Tags: python

```
appoint =[
            ["Time "," Monday "," Tuesday "," Wednesday"," Thrurusday"," Friday"," Saturday"],
            [ "1:00","Availble","Available","Available","Available","Available","Available" ],
            [ "2:00","Available","Available","Available","Available","Available","Available" ],
            [ "3:00","Available","Available","Available","Available","Available","Available" ],
            [ "4:00","Available","Available","Available","Available","Available","Available" ],
            [ "5:00","Available","Available","Available","Available","Available","Available" ]
            ]
for r in appoint:
    for c in r:
        print(c,end = " ")
    print()
choice = int(input("\n Press 1 - Patient Account.\n Press 2 - Doctor Account.\n Press 3 - Exit.\n Enter your choice: "))
print("you choose: " , choice)

if choice == 1:
    print("------ Patient Account ------" )
    choice_patient = int(input("1. To book an appoitment\n 2. Cancel appoint\n 3. Exit\n Enter your choice: "))
    if choice_patient == 1:
        name1 = str(input("Enter name for the appoint booking: "))
        for r in appoint:
            for c in r:
                print(c,end = " ")
        print("       ", appoint)
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: What is the output? And what did you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0):

**FIX:** You need a new line also, as

```
for r in appoint:
    for c in r:
        print(c,end = " ")
    print()
```

**BETTER:** But the easier is

```
for r in appoint:
    print(" ".join(r))
```

**IMPROVE:** And to handle the names that will follow (different size) you may use formatting to ensure you print same-size content

```
for r in appoint:
    print(" ".join(f"{c:<12s}" for c in r))
```

*And remove `print("       ", appoint)`*

Comment: The `print()` statement in the fix version needs to be indented over so you print a new line after every row.

Comment: for r in appoint:
    print(" ".join(f"{c:<12s}" for c in r) 
this code is working but can anyone explain this line what is happening here ?

Comment: @MUHAMMADUZAIR do `print([f"{c:<12s}" for c in r])` each element is formatted, in a 12-length string, then you join them with a space